# Android generate small color difference RGB

Tags: android, canvas, paint, argb

I want to generate/randomize a color and then I want second one that is close to the generated one. 
This is how I generate the colors ftm:

```
Paint colors = new Paint();

int red = ran.nextInt(256-100)+100;
int green = ran.nextInt(256-100)+100;
int blue = ran.nextInt(256-100)+100;

colors.setARGB(255, red, green, blue);
```

and later the 2nd color I generate like this:

```
switch (ran.nextInt(3)) {
        case 0:
            red = red - (40 - level);
            break;
        case 1:
            green = green - (40 - level);
            break;
        default:
            blue = blue - (40-level);
            break;
        }
```

The problem is that it works in some cases and sometimes it can give me a 2nd color that is off by miles. 
Is there another, better and easier way to generate these colors?

br

Comment: there's other color spaces, like hsv, which are better suited to manipulation for producing "similar" colors.

Comment: @MarcB +1 ...and tinyColor.js easily converts between rgb and hsl: http://bgrins.github.io/TinyColor/docs/tinycolor.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a real random number between 0 and 3:

```
 Random ran = new Random();
 int max = 3;
 int min = 0;
 int randomNum = ran.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;

switch (randomNum ) {
        case 0:
            red = red - (40 - level);
            break;
        case 1:
            green = green - (40 - level);
            break;
        default:
            blue = blue - (40-level);
            break;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use java.awt.Color.brighter() and Color.darker().